# I already have a button on my Arduino board, but I don't know what pin number should I use in my code?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm attaching a picture of my board which has the push button I want to use, but I cannot because I don't know what pin number should I write in my code.

my code:

```
int switchPin = Button;
int ledPin =13;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if(digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH)
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
else
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
}
```

This is a picture shows the button on the top right "green"
[image]

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: What does the user manual say? I assume you have read it?

Comment: it doesn't have manual with it!

Comment: and I looked online, but I couldn't find one!

Comment: Abdulrahman, what's the name of the board, or what identifying text is on it, or what do you think it's called?

Comment: I could find this link refrencing that "mCore" board: http://www.makeblock.com/mcore-main-control-board-for-mbot/ However, I'm not sure there is a datasheet (could not find one).

Answer (score 3):

The [schematic at makeblock.com of the mbot mcore board](https://support.makeblock.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412894402967-mCore-Main-Control-Board-for-mBot) shows switch S3 feeding pin A7, which is an analog input pin.  Note, there is a deplorable 0.1 μF capacitor in parallel across S3, probably intended as hardware-level debouncing.

Also see the [Port wiring mBot mCore board](https://forum.makeblock.com/t/port-wiring-mbot-mcore-board/1379) thread on the Makeblock forum, where one of the posts says there are multiple versions of the board, and provides reference links.

For example, sample code at
[newinnovators.ca's “mblock-to-arduino/button-control” page](http://www.newinnovators.ca/index.php/mbot/mblock-to-arduino/button-control) (Dead link) shows pin 2 being used to sense the button.  You may need to run some tests.